# Multi-tenant specific internationalization in Play Framework 1.3.2

Tags: javascript, java, playframework, playframework-1.x

I have an app written in Play Framework (version - 1.3.2).

I have implemented it as a Multi-Tenant based application.
My concern is to keep messages.en file specific to each tenant such that key remains same but text changes as per tenant, which i'd be putting in play as:

play/conf/tenant-folder/tenant_1/messages.en
            
play/conf/tenant-folder/tenant_2/messages.en
            
play/conf/messages.en (default fallback)

I have some idea about extending Implementation of MessagePlugin.java class but how do I intercept &{...} to retrieve values from extended Implementation of Messages.java class.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

IMO the right way to solve your problem is using modules. Create a base `messages.en` for all the messages in your application and place it in your project's conf folder. After that, create a module for each tenant. And add a `messages.en` file including only the messages that you want to override for that tenant.

When you add tenant_1 module to your `dependencies.yml` file, the `messages.en` keys in the `modules/tenant_1/conf/messages.en` file will override the application messages. And you will see the text specialized for your tenant.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a working solution to this problem.

(Create a folder in conf, such as *conf/tenant_1/messages.en*; *conf/tenant_2/messages.en* etc.)

1. Create a class `TenantMessagePlugin.java`, which override the `play.i18n.MessagesPlugin class`.
   Give implementation of `onApplicationStart()` method, to load **conf/tenant_N/messages.en** file of N tenants.
2. Create a File/or use same class and create a `Map<tenant_id,properties file>` which holds the messages.en file for each specific tenant.
3. In class `TenantMessagePlugin`, override the `getMessage()` method of `play.PlayPlugin` class (root plugin parent class), this will return the message from `Map<>` created in (2) for tenant in request, if key is found return the value else return null. Returning null would fallback to original messages.en 
   [The actual implementation of `play.PlayPlugin` returns null for all other classes, but we explicitly hook our method to return value of key - whereas play plugins have an extra class e.g. `play.i18n.Messages.java` to hold `Map<locale, properties>`]
4. create a file in `conf/play.plugins` and add this line {priority:package_name:class_name}
   e.g. `490:tenantcustomisation.TenantMessagePlugin`
   where 490 - priority of custom plugin (should be higher than default `MessagesPlugin` so that framework first checks the tenant's messages.en file)

This should definitely work and `&{'key'}` from html files returns value as desired from `getMessage()` method